# Display text corectly in php, how make?

Tags: php

I have this code but doesn't work correctly.

I want to show Title 1 when not exist has_tag. When exist hst_tag car i want to display only Title 2 and when exist has_tag boat i want to display only Title 3.

```
echo '<h1>Title 1</h1>';
if (has_tag( 'car' )) {
    echo '<h1>Title 2</h1>';
} elseif (has_tag('boat'))   {
    echo "Title 3";
}
```

Comment: Check out this:-https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well ...

```
if (has_tag( 'car' )) {
    echo '<h1>Title 2</h1>';
} elseif (has_tag('boat'))   {
    echo "Title 3";
} else {
    echo '<h1>Title 1</h1>'; // No tag or any other tag besides car and boat
}
```

If you have to make sure there are no tags:

```
if (has_tag( 'car' )) {
    echo '<h1>Title 2</h1>';
} elseif (has_tag('boat'))   {
    echo "Title 3";
} elseif (!has_tag()) {
    echo '<h1>Title 1</h1>'; // No tag
}
```